# Dynamics Crm 2011 error while registering the plugin

Tags: javascript, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

i am coompletely new to this plugin part of crm 2011.

I wrote a simple plugin.Generated a xrm.cs file
and tried registering the plugin but it was giving some "Time out exception"
Later on i removed the Xrm.cs file from my solution and then the plugin got registered.
i did not understand why this happened.

Below is my simple plugin code which is not getting invoked maybe because i removed Xrm.cs file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;




namespace NewPlugin
{
public class Plugin : IPlugin
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A plugin that creates a follow-up task activity when a new account is created.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Register this plug-in on the Create message, account entity,
    /// and asynchronous mode.
    /// </remarks>
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        //Extract the tracing service for use in debugging sandboxed plug-ins.
        ITracingService tracingService =
            (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));
        account 
        // Obtain the execution context from the service provider.
        IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)
            serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

        // The InputParameters collection contains all the data passed in the message request.
        if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") &&
            context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
        {
            // Obtain the target entity from the input parameters.
            Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("not Possible");

        }
    }
}
}
```

Please if anybody can give me an idea whats wrong wid my Xrm.cs file it would be of great help.

This the exception i am getting onclick of Create button on Accounts Page

```
Unhandled Exception:    System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: An error occurred. Contact a system administrator or refer to the Microsoft Dynamics CRM SDK troubleshooting guide.Detail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
<ErrorCode>-2147220891</ErrorCode>
<ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
<KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
  <d2p1:key>OperationStatus</d2p1:key>
  <d2p1:value xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d4p1:string">0</d2p1:value>
</KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
</ErrorDetails>
<Message>An error occurred. Contact a system administrator or refer to the Microsoft Dynamics CRM SDK troubleshooting guide.</Message>
<Timestamp>2013-10-28T04:51:39.2540481Z</Timestamp>
<InnerFault i:nil="true" />
<TraceText>

[ActivityFeeds.Plugins: ActivityFeeds.Plugins.ActivityClose]
[34685442-783d-e311-a318-b4b52f6727c4: ActivityFeeds.Plugins.ActivityClose: Create of account]
```

Comment: Please insert exception details in your question. It will be probably easier to help you

Comment: What was in your 'Xrm.cs' file?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are not deploy manager (you can check it in the crm org manager) and that plugin is not registered in isolation mode. 
You can you try to install the crm developer toolkit inside the sdk (SDK\Tools\DeveloperToolkit) for an easier deploy/registration.
That will allow to create a new solution with a package, a plugin project and if connected to the proper crm and solution you will be able to let VS to create the base class for you.